# Program that calculates the first n powers of x

Tags: beginner, c

I am a beginner. I wrote a C program that calculates the first `n` powers of `x` and I don't even know if this is legit C code or strictly C++ code. Please criticize it and help me improve it.

```
#include <stdlib.h> //to use malloc and delete
#include <stdio.h> //to use printf

#define uint64 unsigned long long int //for simplicity

/* this program calculates the first n powers of x*/

uint64* Pow (int x, unsigned char n)
{
    uint64* retVal = (uint64*)malloc(sizeof(uint64));
    *retVal = 1;

    for (unsigned char i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        *retVal *= x;
    }

    return retVal;
}

void calculateFirstNPowers(int x, unsigned char n)
{
    uint64 sum = 0;
    uint64* Pow_retValPtr;

    for (unsigned char i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        Pow_retValPtr = ::Pow(x, i);

        printf("%d. Power of %d: ", i, x);
        printf("%d\n", *Pow_retValPtr);

        sum += *Pow_retValPtr;

        free(Pow_retValPtr);
    }

    printf("\nsum of first %d powers of %d: %d", n, x, sum);
}

int main()
{
    calculateFirstNPowers(2, 7);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know what compiler you are using and what command-line flags you are invoking it with to build your program.

Comment: @200_success MSVC (cl command on CMD) and I don't use any flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review!

### C or C++

Technically, this could be compiled as both C and C++, were it not for line 28:

```
Pow_retValPtr = ::Pow(x, i);
```

The scope resolution operator `::` is only defined in C++, compiling this as C doesn't work.

Since I don't know too much about good C++, I'll treat this as if it was a C program as it reads more like C to me. Maybe someone more knowledgeable can add something about C++ in another answer.

### `uint64`

Use `typedef` instead of `#define`:

```
typedef uint64 unsigned long long int;
```

The name also might cause confusion with the typedef `uint64_t` found in `inttypes.h`. Consider using this header directly instead of defining your own type.

### `Pow()`

Why does this function not return the value directly? This way, there wouldn't be the need to allocate memory *inside* the function and then remember to free it *outside* the function. If you forget the latter part, some memory will be leaking every time the function is called, which is undesirable. Here's how the function would look:

```
uint64 Pow (int x, unsigned char n)
{
    uint64 retVal = 1;

    for (unsigned char i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        retVal *= x;
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

You could also pass a pointer to a result variable as an argument to the function, but that makes the function a bit weird to use. How to do this is left as an exercise for the reader.

### Printing

This shouldn't compile without any warnings. Both `sum` and `Pow_retValPtr` are/refer to a value of the type `uint64/unsigned long long int`, but the format `%d` is used for signed integers. The correct format to use is `%llu`.

The last `printf` doesn't end with a line break which looks ugly when the program is run from a terminal:

```
mindoverflow@pc:~/$ ./a.out
1. Power of 2: 2
...
5. Power of 2: 32

sum of first 5 powers of 2: 62mindoverflow@pc:~/$ 
mindoverflow@pc:~/$
```

Please add one!

### Variable naming

`x` and `n` could be more descriptive. I'd suggest something like this:

```
uint64 Pow (int base, unsigned char power) ...

void calculateFirstNPowers(int base, unsigned char n)...
```

In the second case, the N in the function name describes the argument, so I didn't change it.

`Pow_retValPtr` could also just be renamed to `power`, as this is descriptive enough in the context IMO, especially, if you change `Pow()` as described above.

There also is a joke about naming a variable `powerptr` somewhere here ... :)

Comment: this is so extremely helpful. thank you. 

Also I made Pow() return a pointer because I didn't want to call the function Pow() 2 times inside calculateFirstNPowers() and I didn't want to copy the value it returns to a new variable. So I decided to use pointers.

Thank you because I didn't know I have to use "%llu" and there is no :: in C.

I learned so much useful stuff from your answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things that is worth pointing out from strictly the C++ point of view.

The code you have written, while still being valid C++, seems structured kind of in a C-fashioned way; there are a lot of C++ specific features that may be used to improve it.

##### C Headers

In C++ including `stdio.h` should be avoided. The C++ standard library provides the `iostream` header for IO operations. For example, the two following snippets are equivalent:

```
// C-fashion
#include <stdio.h>

void print_sum(int a, int b) {
    printf("%i\n", a + b);
}
```

```
// C++ fashion
#include <iostream>

void print_sum(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
}
```

I'm not sure whether the inclusion of C headers is still possible in C++, if it's just a compiler extension, or if it's just intended for backwards compatibility.

##### Allocation

Avoid using C dynamic allocation in C++ (`malloc`, `calloc`... etc `stdlib.h` functions). C++ introduces the `new` keyword. [Refer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new/70614139#70614139).

##### Headers

In the rare occasions where you *really* need a C header included. C++ has its own bindings for that.

```
#include <cstdio>  // C's stdio.h
#include <cstdlib> // C's stdlib.h
```

Take a look at [this C++ reference for](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/) .

##### Naming convention

*This is just a suggestion*, you are free to use whatever naming convention you feel comfortable with as long as your code is not supposed to be part of a pre-existing project. Consistency is the first thing.
I would rather use `lowercase_with_underscores` names for local variables and functions.
I'd suggest you to take a look at [Google C++ Style Format](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html).

Apart from this there's the define thing of [mindoverflow's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/278209/256709)

Comment: but I want it to be C code

Comment: @AnaKullanıcı That's C++ code. Namespaces are a C++ thing.

Comment: namespace? where?

Comment: @AnaKullanıcı C++'s scope resolution operator :: is not a valid operator in C ;)

Comment: oh. thank you for telling me that. I didn't know

Answer (score 0):

## Naming conventions

`#define uint64 unsigned long long int` is misleading, as [unsigned long long](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types) is only guaranteed to be *at least* 64 bits, while a programmer may reasonably expect `uint64` to be exactly 64 bits in terms of memory usage and maybe [unsigned overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is) (which is guaranteed to wraparound in the C standard). C99 already gives you [`uint64_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) in `<stdint.h>` which is exactly 64 bits and could be confused with your custom type.

`uint64* Pow (int x, unsigned char n)`: I would be careful naming a function `Pow` because it could be confused with [`pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) defined in `<math.h>`. But you can argue the capitalization makes it clear it's different enough for programmers.

Also why is `n` an `unsigned char`? I don't think it will actually save space or run faster on a modern system with 32 or 64 bit words (I'm not sure on this). But even if you limit `n` to an unsigned char, it can still overflow so you don't get any safety from that.

For a toy program it's fine not to handle overflow, but I would expect documentation for any kind of arithmetic function to document how overflow is handled, if at all.